# Control reaches end of non-void function, C++

Tags: python, c++

I tried searching around, but didn't really find any answer to my question. My task is to translate the following code(Python) into C++:

```
def triangleNumbersBelow(n):
    acc = 1
    num = 2
    print("Triangle numbers below ", n, ":", sep="") 
    while acc < n:
         print(acc) 
         acc += num 
         num += 1
    print()
```

My attempt:

```
int triangleNumbersBelow(int n) {
    int acc = 1;
    int num = 2;
    cout << "Triangle numbers below" << n;
    while (acc < n) {
        cout << acc << '\n';
        acc += num;
        num += 1;
    }
    cout << "";
}
```

But I get the error message "Control reaches end of non-void function". Could anyone help me?

Comment: You promised to return an `int` but failed to do so. The compiler is warning you about this undefined behavior.

Comment: unrelated:  `cout << "";` wont do anything

Comment: I would suggest that you don't translate languages line by line (it doesn't work in spoken languages, and it doesn't work in these either).  You need to know both languages well enough to use either, and then you can read one, understand what it's doing, and then translate "in your own words" ....

sure - it takes longer, but how can you be sure that it couldn't be done in a single line otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int triangleNumbersBelow(int n) {` means the function has to return an *int* value, but you never did

in fact you do not have to return a value because the python version don't return a value, so change its signature by `void triangleNumbersBelow(int n) {`

---

I propose you to also

- replace `cout << "Triangle numbers below" << n;` by `cout << "Triangle numbers below" << n << endl;` else *n* will be collapsed with the first value of *acc*
- remove your last `cout << "";` or replace it by `cout << endl;`

Comment: Technically, the Python version returned the result of the `print`, which is the value `None`.  Which was probably discarded/ignored by the caller.

Comment: Thanks! what about the main function? When I try to call the triangleNumbersBelow inside the int main-function, I get "Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'void')"

Comment: @Jmei _triangleNumbersBelow_ waits for an integer, it seems you give an _ostream_ (may be _cout_ ?). What is your code in _main_ ?

Comment: @Jmei 1) You don't show your `main` function. 2) I guess that what you are trying to do something like `std::cout << triangleNumbersBelow(n);`. Since one cannot print `void` values (since there are no value to print), there can be 2 solutions: Either print everything you want in `triangleNumbersBelow` function (as you are doing currently), and not pass its value to `cout`, or make it, to actually `return` something you might want to print.

Comment: You will have to show what you did in main. I suspect you tried `std::cout << triangleNumbersBelow(somenumber);` and that can't work because triangleNumbersBelow() does not return anything.

Comment: int main() {
 cout << triangleNumbersBelow(10) << '\n';
}

Comment: @Jmei just replace that by `int main() { triangleNumbersBelow(10); return 0;}`

Comment: replace `cout << triangleNumbersBelow(10) << '\n'; ` with `triangleNumbersBelow(10);`

Comment: Thank you! but why?

Comment: @Jmei the function doesn't return a value, else you need to change it to return _acc_ at the end of the body, and of course reintroduce `int triangleNumbersBelow(int n) ...`, but this is not compatible with the python code

Comment: You can't print a `void` because its not a value.

Answer (score 0):

check your function body of translated C++

the return type of function is int and there's no return at the end of the function